# Pagination not working in category listing

Tags: loop, query-posts

I can't get pagination inside categories listings to work.

I'm using a custom query, with the `get_query_var('paged')`:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args=array(
'post__not_in'=>$essentielle_excluded_posts,
'category_name' => 'concours-fun',
'paged'=>$paged, 
'posts_per_page'=>5,
);
query_posts($args);
```

Also tried the Category Pagination Fix plugin.

My permalink structure: `/%category%/%postname%-%post_id%.html`

Example of the error: http://www.essentielle.be/concours-fun/page/2

Any idea as to what else i should check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get_query_var('paged')` should be `get_query_var('page')`, however, you should use a [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action hook to alter the query rather than using `query_posts` in the template, which is a waste of resources ([see this answer for more info](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/4771)).